# How do I program something to get the number of possible outcomes in PHP?

Tags: php, math, combinations

There are 3 boxes: `boxA`, `boxB` and `boxC`

You can put either `1` or `0` in each box

The possible outcomes are `1,1,1` `1,1,0` `1,0,0` `0,0,0` `0,0,1` `0,1,1` `0,1,0` `1,0,1`

So the answer is 8.

How do I code this if I could edit the number of variables? Like the number of boxes or the number of inputs I could do, not just 1 or 0.

Is it close to combination with repetition? I am not sure.

Comment: Basically just treat as a binary number of 3 digits. But as SO *isn't* a code writing service, show your attempt.

Comment: Just multiply the number of possible values for each box together? 2*2*2 or 2^3

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I code this"? If this is a fixed set of data, the result is also pretty fixed. If not, could you come up with a solution in words first, and try to program it afterwards?

Comment: OP has yet to weigh in on any of these good suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple answer that will give you all possible outcomes, which is 2 to the power of 3 (2**3), so 2 (all the possible values you can assign) to the power of 3 (all the items you have to assign those values, the boxes).

So **2**3 = 2*2*2 = 8**

Answer (score 1):

```
$possibilities = $number_of_variables ** $number_of_boxes
```